Fresh loading and insert image from Webserver
First of all: I'm unfortunately not very familiar with PowerPoint or VBA. I tried to solve it with ChatGPT, but I can't get it to work. I have a presentation with 10 different slides. The presentation runs 24/7 and always starts over. On slides 4, 8, 12 and 16 I want to display an image that is on a server that is accessible on the Internet. It is a .jpg and I can access it directly via the URL (example: https://myserver.com/myimage.jpg)
Important: The image always has the same name, but the content of the image can change. So when the above slides are displayed, I want the image to always be freshly loaded from the server and nothing to be fetched from the cache or anything like that. The size of the image in the slide should be adjustable in the code.
Can someone help me with this? Or does anyone have a sample PowerPoint that already contains a working macro or something that I just need to adapt? I've spent the whole day with ChatGPT and Google and nothing worked. I'm starting to despair. 2024 and PowerPoint can't display an image from a specific URL out of the box and without the help of scripts and add-ons...
I tried using ChatGPT, but the VBA code suggested to me didn't work. No image was inserted, the slide remained blank.
This is the code from ChatGPT:

Private Sub App_SlideShowNextSlide(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
    Dim sld As slide
    Dim shp As shape
    Dim imgURL As String

    ' URL des Bildes
    imgURL = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png"

    ' Auf die aktuelle Folie zugreifen
    Set sld = Wn.View.Slide

    ' Bild mit dem Namen "LiveBild" löschen und neu hinzufügen
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.Name = "LiveBild" Then
            shp.Delete
        End If
    Next shp

    sld.Shapes.AddPicture imgURL, msoFalse, msoCTrue, 100, 100, -1, -1 ' Position und Größe anpassen
End Sub


There's a reason people describe ChatGPT as an but very drunk intern. It's given you code that might almost work as part of an installed add-in, but never in a PPTM.
It will work if you change the first line to
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)  

but it'll put your image on every page. You then need to modify the code to have it work only if the newly viewed page is one of the ones you're after. Here's a modified version that only puts the image on slide 2:
Option Explicit

Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim imgURL As String

    ' URL des Bildes
    imgURL = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png"

    ' Auf die aktuelle Folie zugreifen
    Set sld = Wn.View.Slide

    ' DELETE any image already there, regardless of slide number
    ' Bild mit dem Namen "LiveBild" löschen und neu hinzufügen
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.Name = "LiveBild" Then
            shp.Delete
        End If
    Next shp

    If sld.SlideIndex = 2 Then
        set shp = sld.Shapes.AddPicture imgURL, msoFalse, msoCTrue, 100, 100, -1, -1 ' Position und Größe anpassen
        shp.Name = "LiveBild" 
    End If
    
End Sub


After AddPicture, you should give the shape the name "LiveBild", else a new picture is added without deleting the previous.

In this case, ChatGPT was not so much drunken but lazy. The event App_SlideShowNextSlide will work, but you need to create an EventHandler - this whole story with creating a class with WithEvents... See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/powerpoint/how-to/use-events-with-the-application-object

True, IF you intend to create an addin from the code. Otherwise, the intern's still drunk. :-)
